# tool or technique to get a diff of two different linux installations

Tags: configuration, version-control

Albert Einstein [quote](http://thinkexist.com/quotation/insanity-doing_the_same_thing_over_and_over_again/15511.html)

> Insanity: doing the same thing over and over
>   again and expecting different results

Often-times, Linux drives me mad because I'm doing the same thing over and over again and *getting* different results from box to box. (See [my previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13473/why-does-the-adduser-command-behave-surprisingly)).

For me, the biggest area of confusion is taking over a machine that someone else has installed (as is the case when signing up with a web hosting company). You just don't know what you're dealing with.

**Is there some kind of clever *diff tool* that I can run on an installation of Linux (Ubuntu) to give me a heads-up on how that machine has veered from the default installation?**

i.e. Something that can show me a list of the commands that are going to behave surprisingly thus avoiding a trial and error approach.

Comment: You won't get a “list of the commands that are going to behave surprisingly”. Software can't predict what you'll find surprising.

Comment: Thanks. These answers are giving me better understanding of how to model the _pertinent areas of difference_ that need to be considered when taking over a machine that someone else has installed. 

So far we have differences in: _packages installed_, _running services_, _configurations_ and _file system type_. I'm interested to know if that's it or is the list infinite?  

@Gilles - yes, with limited knowledge of linux, I find it hard to predict what I'd 'find surprising' myself as well!

Comment: The list is infinite. Not a Linux example, but a while ago, Visual Studio wouldn't show some dialog boxes on a particular machine (no error, just empty space where the controls should have been). It turned out to be due to having too many fonts installed. The moral of this story is that there will always be surprises lurking in corners.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whenever I have a good reference system and a misbehaving one, I try to compare them with vimdiff. What I compare varies with the problem, e.g.

1) When comparing servers at the package level, I create sorted lists of packages on each server, send the results to files and diff them, e.g.

On server1:

```
dpkg --get-selections|sort > server1_packages
```

On server2:

```
dpkg --get-selections|sort > server2_packages
```

Copy both files to the same machine and diff (or vimdiff) them.

2) Make a list of running services as in example 1

```
sysv-rc-conf --list|sort > server1_services

sysv-rc-conf --list|sort > server2_services
```

...etc., and vimdiff those.

3) If you are troubleshooting inconsistent configurations with Apache for example, make copies of the config files, and vimdiff those, etc.

Comment: Good summary of options. It is also a good idea to put files under `/etc` under version control to help you keep track of what is going on. `etckeeper` will do this for you.

Comment: I am getting "dpkg: failed to open package info file `/var/lib/dpkg/status' for reading: No such file or directory". How would this look on Centos with yum? PS Nevermind, found it "yum list installed"

Answer (score 5):

Most of the differences between two installations of the same distribution will be in `/etc`. Copy the contents of `/etc` from one machine to a temporary directory on the other and run

```
diff -ru /etc /copy/of/other/etc
```

If you want to compare a machine with a default installation, get a copy from a fresh default installation (perhaps in a virtual machine).

If you can control a machine from the start, make sure to install [etckeeper](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/etckeeper/) to keep `/etc` under version control. Then you'll be able to see precisely what's changed.

Of course, there'll be a lot of differences. If you don't yet have an idea of where to look, this is the wrong approach to investigate a particular difference in behavior. For example, let's say the command `adduser` behaves differently on two machines. Then the best approach is to look at what `adduser` is doing; run it on both machines and compare. If it has an option to tell it to be more verbose (`adduser` doesn't), use it. More radically, run the program under [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace), e.g.

```
strace -s9999 -efile adduser …
```

to see what files `adduser` accesses.

Answer (score 2):

To harken back to an earlier question, your nifty tool, which sounds like a good idea to me, but I've never heard of such a beast existing, needs to check things like filesystem type and sizes.

A real life example that happened to me in 2002: two people installed SuSE 7.3 systems on two adjacent rack-mounted servers. They put a lot of effort into getting the packages exactly the same on both servers.  A short while later, we had problems with some software in development.  It came down to ext3 filesystem on one server, Reiserfs on the other.  A plain "ls" on Reiserfs gives file names in lexical order, but not on ext3.  One program failed on out-of-order filenames.

Answer (score 1):

For files, users, groups, packages, services etc I've used http://www.scriptrock.com; it's free for a few servers and gives you a nice visual comparison of the differences between the servers..very handy for drift